# Prevent bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file from being placed in custom-set-variables

Tags: init-file, customize, bookmarks

I have the following code to set a `custom.el` file and load [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus):

```el
(setq custom-file  (concat elf-emacs-lib-home-directory "emacs-config/" "custom.el"))
(when (file-exists-p custom-file) (load custom-file :noerror))

(setq bookmark-default-file  (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/.emacs.d/.bookmarks"))

(use-package bookmark+              ;;; Bookmark+: extensions to standard library `bookmark.el'.
  :init
  (defvar bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file)
  (defvar bmkp-bmenu-state-file)
  (setq bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file bookmark-default-file) ;; load the the last-used bookmark file first
  (setq bmkp-bmenu-state-file            (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/.emacs.d/.bmk-bmenu-state.el")))
```

My problem is that I keep getting this in my custom-set-variables:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file "/users/name/.emacs.d/.bookmarks")
```

How do I prevent this variable from being placed in `custom-set-variables`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please explain **why** you do not want that user option to be saved in your `custom-file`.  That's the logical place for it.  User options are saved in `custom-file` if it exists, or in your init file otherwise.
2. If you really do not want it to be saved there , and you do not want it to be customizable (using Customize), you can do this:

   ```
   (put 'bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file 'standard-value nil)
   ```

   You can still set it using, say, `setq`.  And you can still save it in some other way.

---

**Update after comments -**

I see what's happening.  The point of this option is to let you choose to use start a new Emacs session using the last bookmark file that was used in your last Emacs session.  If you *want* that then *that value needs to be saved*.  It is saved in your `custom-file`.

You are anyway *not* saving that information in any way -- `use-package` and your use of `use-package` do not do anything like that.

All you are doing is setting that option value to the value of `bookmark-default-file` each time you start an Emacs session.

If you want to use the value of `bookmark-default-file` each time you start an Emacs session then option `bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file` should be **`nil`**.  Customize the value to be `nil` and your problem should go away.  The behavior you will get will be to use the *same* bookmark file each time you start Emacs (more precisely, the value of `bookmark-default-file`, which you could of course change from one session to another in some way).

Here is the doc of option `bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file`. Please pay special attention to what I've put in **bold**.  Let me know, if you still have a question.

> bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file is a variable defined in [`bookmark+-1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/bookmark%2b-1.el)().
>
> Its value is "..."
>
> Documentation:
>
> Whether to use the last-used bookmark file as the first used.
>
> **If `nil` then Emacs always uses the value of `bookmark-default-file` as
>   the initial bookmark file, in any given session.**
>
> If non-`nil`, Emacs uses the last bookmark file you used, in the last
>   Emacs session.  If none was recorded then it uses
>   `bookmark-default-file`.  The particular non-`nil` value must be an
>   absolute file name (possibly containing `~`) - it is not expanded).
>
> **NOTE: A non-`nil` option value is overwritten by Bookmark+, so that it
>   becomes the last-used bookmark file.  A `nil` value is never
>   overwritten.**
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: I don't want it there because I explicitly set it in the use-package command which is called from my init.el file. Variables being set in multiple places is confusing at best. I set the variable explicitly so I don't want to see it in custom-set-variables. I version control all my emacs files including `custom.el`.  The real problem is when I change systems the `substitute-in-file-name` gets expanded to properly point to the correct file. And the value in custom doesn't update the way I'd like it to. So the easiest thing for me is just remove it.

Comment: I'm still getting it in custom.el but now I get `'(bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file "/users/my_name/.emacs.d/.bookmarks" t)`

Comment: If you don't use Customize (or its functions) to change and save the value then it shouldn't be saved in your `custom-file`. But of course if you did ever use Customize to do that then it is still in your `custom-file`. Did you try editing your `custom-file` to remove it? Or did you try using Customize to reset the value to the standard value (so you can then set it in some other way, such as `use-package`)? It's not clear to me just what you are doing, but a guess is that its presence in your `custom-file` is just vestigial - try removing it.

Comment: I'm constantly deleting it out of my `custom.el` and it keeps getting placed back in there. I have never used customize for this, only set it through my init.el.  This is the only variable I have problems with and I have at least 30 packages and I set all kinds of custom things. I think it might do this when emacs closes. I see it says saving bookmarks...

Comment: Thank you so much Drew! I see it in the documentation now. My apologies, I should have read the documentation once I saw the behavior.

Comment: No problem. It's a good question. And the option is a bit unusual and so a bit hard to describe. And I wasn't too clear on what you were doing or wanting to do.